# Win 10 Параметры - Устройства - не открывается

Tags: windows-10

Win 10 Ent Ltsc 1809 + Все обновления.

Сабж. Жму - Пуск, Параметры, открылось. При клике на "Устройства (Блютус, принтеры..)" - окно на секунду показывается, после сразу закрывается. Остальные открываются норм.

Это от адм. в PS делал, не помогло:

`Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Что еще может быть? Можно его еще как-то открыть?

Comment: а попробуйте ка в безопасном режиме. если результат такой же, вполне возможно, какой нибудь косяк реестра (сомневаюсь что у вас есть его бэкап). если раньше всё работало - попробуйте откатить винду

Comment: Прив. Спасибо за ответ. Пробовал. Пробовал и от(+входя) УЗ л.админа (хотя сам работаю под УЗ с такими правами). Есть аналогичная сборка W10 ltsb 1607, там тоже аналогично. В loc.GPO есть ограничения, но нет похожих.

Comment: может просто сборка сама по себе кривая?

Comment: изначально это работало, но после каких-то обновлений перестало

Comment: если очень критично, пробуйте откатить на день до обновы. Если та точка восстановления еще не затёрлась